# Wordpress Media Upload Database Error Duplicate Entry

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I moved servers with a different hosting company and the website was working fine... Tried database repair, it ran and completed. Nothing seems to be fixing the issue.

When I go to add products and for some reason I cannot add images to the media folder. I get the following error message with debug on. My products update by cron usually and all my images are missing because it tried to update them. They are being uploaded though but I get the placeholder in the admin and front end. Debug error during upload:

```
WordPress database error: [Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY']
INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `post_type`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_parent`, `menu_order`, `post_mime_type`, `guid`) VALUES (1, '2017-04-21 14:43:57', '2017-04-21 18:43:57', '', '', 'A1990B-021', '', 'inherit', 'attachment', 'open', 'closed', '', 'a1990b-021', '', '', '2017-04-21 14:43:57', '2017-04-21 18:43:57', 0, 0, 'image/jpeg', 'http://www.myurlishere.com/wp-content/uploads/A1990B-021-1.jpg')

0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit my sql table. The issue was auto increment would not enable due to it trying to set the default value as 0. Went in the table structure and located the ID that had 0 under the wp_posts. It was only a "auto draft" so I deleted it. Went back to wp_posts and enabled auto increment and now working!